# Summation of elements of dictionary that are list of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
d = {
  'a': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]],
  'b': [[2, 4, 1], [1, 6, 1]],
}

def add_element(lst):
    ad = [sum(i) for i in zip(*lst)]
    return ad

def csv_reducer2(dicty):
    return {k: list(map(add_element, v)) for k, v in dicty.items()}

csv_reducer2(d)
```

required output:

```
{'b': [3, 10, 2], 'a': [2, 4, 6]}
```

Above is the code I have been trying but it gives an error

> zip argument #1 must support iteration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will work on Python 2 or 3:

```
>>> {k: [a + b for a, b in zip(*v)] for k, v in d.items()}
{'a': [2, 4, 6], 'b': [3, 10, 2]}
```

The issue with your code is you are mapping `add_element` to every individual element in `v` inside your dictionary comprehension. This passes a one-dimensional list to `zip` in `add_element`, resulting in your error (since individual integers don't support iteration.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> d = {'a': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], 'b': [[2, 4, 1], [1, 6, 1]]}
>>> {k: map(sum, zip(*v)) for k, v in d.items()}
{'a': [2, 4, 6], 'b': [3, 10, 2]}
```

Comment: As @juanpa.arrivillaga alluded to, on Python 3 you must use `list(map(..))`

Answer (score 4):

To fix your original code, the only change you need to make is:

```
return {k: list(map(add_element, v)) for k, v in dicty.items()}
```

->

```
return {k: add_element(v) for k, v in dicty.items()}
```

Because `zip(*lst)` is trying to transpose multiple rows into columns, but you are only passing it single rows through your original `map`

Comment: Thank you very much  jamylak, juanpa.arrivillaga I gradually figured it out and made a change in my code

Comment: return {k: list(map(sum, zip(*v))) for k, v in dict_1.items()}